# Cauchy integral calculation outside the region

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

I have an integral $\oint \frac{2z}{z^2-9}dz$. It's said that the integral taken around the circle |z|=2 Here, the roots of z are $3,-3$ so it's outside the region. Does it mean the integral is 0?

Comment: yes, because the integrand is holomorphic inside the circle of radius $2$.

Comment: it's a ring, not a circle and said "around". Eventhough, is still $0$ right?

Comment: yes i meant the integrand is holonorphic in the (simply connected) open disc $U=\{z\, :\, |z|<3\} $, and the ring/circle (however you want to call it) of radius 2 lies inside $U$ therefore the integral is 0